# Translate "hard-coded" part of the routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, translation

i'm trying to translate the "hard-coded" part of the routes in my web.php but I don't know what's missing in order to make it works. The native language is french and i want an english translation.

My code :

web.php

```
Route::get('/'.trans('routes.produit').'/{slug}.html', 'HomeController@product')->name('product');
```

ressources/lang/en/routes.php

```
return [
    'produit' => 'product',
];
```

Currently, no matter the selected lang in my app, it is always translated to "product"

Comment: i never try this one, but please make sure that you have added a new lang folder in resources/lang/fr/route.php. if you using LaravelLocalization, localeCode list are there in config/laravellocalization.php both translation file also must have the same key

Comment: @AlzafanChristian I already have a fr/routes.php but nothing changes

Comment: how are you "selecting" a language in your app? and is this selection adjusting the configuration for `app.locale`?

Comment: i've tested with LaravelLocalization, its worked return 404 if locale value not match uri. then its your app not switching locale. never thought of this, but its working xD

Comment: @lagbox I have a middleware doing :

`if(Session::has('locale')){
            $locale = Session::get('locale');
        }
        elseif(env('DEFAULT_LANGUAGE') != null){
            $locale = env('DEFAULT_LANGUAGE');
        }
        else{
            $locale = 'en';
        }

        App::setLocale($locale);
        $request->session()->put('locale', $locale);`

And also a select button on front doing barely the same thing

Comment: btw, you should not be calling `env` outside of the config files; if you cache your configuration all calls to `env` will return `null` ... also you know that your routes are registered before your route middleware has ran?

Comment: @lagbox Well, so is there any way of doing what i want without any prefix such as fr/ or /en ?